# What is the geometric relation between $z$ and$\sqrt{i}$ $\overline {z\sqrt{-i}}$

Tags: complex-numbers

The answer in the book is like this :
For one value of $\sqrt{-i}$ the point $\sqrt{-i}$ is obtained by rotating $z$ by an angle $\frac{\pi}{2}$, so the diagonal goes into the real  axis by multiplication $\sqrt{-i}$. Similarly we have a rotation when multiplicating by $\sqrt{i}$ by $\frac{\pi}{2}$. So $z$ and $\overline {z\sqrt{-i}}$ is obtained by rotating the plane until the diagonal lies along the real axis, then reflecting by the real axis and then rotating back by the same amount. So $z$ and $\overline{z\sqrt{-i}}$ are reflections of each other through the diagonal.

Now when I do my calculations this answer doesn't seem correct so can someone tell me if I am wrong or give a complete solution to see where my mistakes are?

Comment: Could you show the calculation?

Comment: Well to me the end result is that  if $z=a+bi$ then the expression gives $b+ai$ some kind of permutation of the coordinates, they are really  long

Comment: Do you understand why multiplication by $\sqrt{i}$ is a rotation by $\pi/2$?

Comment: I think that it is a rotation by $\frac{\pi}{4}$ if we find the roots of $i= z^2$